# ( QNativeSocketEngine) QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, network-programming, signals-slots

I'm having a problem which was ask here for a similar situation a couple of times, however I couldn't find the solution in those topics.

I'm having a main class where I'd like to extend it with a qt-network support, and this by an additional class. Let me break the source code down for you to the relevant parts:

**main class**

*.h*

```
class MainClass: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
[...]
private:
    NetworkSupport * netSupport;
};
```

*.cpp*

```
MainClass::MainClass()
{
    [...]
    netSupport
    netSupport = new NetworkSupport(this->thread());
    netSupport->start();
    [...]
}
```

**network class**

*.h*

```
class NetworkSupport : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    NetworkSupport(QThread *mainThread);
    ~NetworkSupport();

    QByteArray readData();
    void sendData(QByteArray *msg);

public slots:
    void acceptConnection();
    void receive();
    void run();

private:
    QByteArray curMessage;
    QThread* libThread;
    QEventLoop initWlan;

protected:
    QTcpServer server;
    QTcpSocket* client;
};
```

*.cpp*

```
NetworkSupport::NetworkSupport(QThread* mainThread)
{
    libThread = mainThread;
    server.moveToThreaD(libThread);
    server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5200);

    QMetaObject::invokeMethode(&initWlan, "quit", Qt:QueuedConnection);
    initWlan.exec();
}

void NetworkSupport::run(){
    connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));
}

void NetworkSupport::acceptConnection()
{
    client = server.nextPendingConnection();
    client->moveToThread(libThread);

    if (client->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
        connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receive()));

}

void NetworkSupport::receive()
{
    curMessage = client->readAll();
}

void NetworkSupport::sendData(QByteArray* msg)
{
    if(client->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        client->moveToThread(libThread);
        printf("Sending a message %s\n",msg->data());
        client->write(*msg);
        client->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
}
```

I know I usually don't need to specifiy the `moveToThread()` this much, but it doesn't change a thing in the end, if all of them are there or removed.

However when executing I get the error message at `client->write(*msg)` in `sendData()`, that is:

```
[...]
Sending a message ?r
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QnativeSocketEngine(0x2afc660), parent's thread is QThread(0x1b59210), current thread is QThread(0x7f6a70026b60)
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
[...]
```

It does look like a warning, since the the program is still in execution afterwards, but I don't receive any messages from the client (i.e. `receive()` gets never executed), which is I guess because of the last line from the error message.

Could it be that this error message is just misleading and if so what's it actual meaning, or did I do something completely wrong?

Comment: how sendData is invoked?

Comment: @Kamil Klimek it's a public function. I.e. whenever the user/main application needs to send a message. Without any signals/slots

Comment: I need to know how it is called - it's important to know on which thread you execute write on socket

Comment: @KamilKlimek for instance: `QByteArray msg = QByteArray::fromRawData("?r",2);` and then `netSupport->sendData(&msg);`

Comment: Ok, you didn't undersand quite wiell my question, so I'll ask another one - are you 100% sure, that you're calling sendData on same thread as the socket resides on

Comment: @KamilKlimek well no, but that's why I'm using so many `moveToThread()`s. However I'm using the `sendData` just in the main application, and to ensure it is the same thread for both I passed the thread of the main application to the network-support constructor, i.e. `netSupport = new NetworkSupport(this->thread());`

Comment: you are misunderstunding parent-child relation with thread affinity

Comment: @KamilKlimek I'm sorry but I'm not sure what to do with this information. I pass the main thread to the network constructor, so everything can be moved to the main thread, I'm not sure why this interferes with inheritance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106506/discussion-between-kamil-klimek-and-user3085931).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing so many things wrong in this code that I'm not sure what to start with.

```
NetworkSupport::NetworkSupport(QThread* mainThread)
{
    libThread = mainThread;
    server.moveToThreaD(libThread);
```

This will do nothing. `server` is already in same thread as MainClass instance

```
    server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5200);
```

Server will start to listen on same thread as MainClass

```
    QMetaObject::invokeMethode(&initWlan, "quit", Qt:QueuedConnection);
    initWlan.exec();
```

This mocks me a lot. This will simply start event loop and quit it almost immedietly.

```
}

void NetworkSupport::run(){
    connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));
}
```

This will simply run in new thread, call connect and quit thread right after connect statement - your thread will not be running anymore after `connect`. Also slot `acceptConnection` will be probably called in same thread as MainClass. I wonder when and where is MainClass created.

Seems for me like you're struggling with to many things at same time. You probably read somwhere, that you should use separate thread for network communicaton, so you won't block other threads. Try single thread approach first. When you get that working, then you should think how to utilize other thread for what you need.

Bonus question: Is this code some kind of plugin for application that may not have Qt eventloop at all? Or is it part of the full-stack Qt application?

Comment: Thanks for conduction. 1) as I said there are too many `moveToThread()`s 2) the `invokeMethod` is doing as you said on purpose. It starts the Signal/Slots interaction for the networking, but doesn't hang on the `.exec()` since it gives back control to the main QEventLoop. 3) `acceptConnection` is running fine, just not the `client->write()` (and possibly more). However I'm not infront of the project atm, so I'm going to double check these points when I return. Bonus question: there is a main QEventLoop :), where this program is integrated to

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misunderstandings in your code how Qt networking and multi threading works.

First, in Qt docs they say on `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()`:

> The returned QTcpSocket object cannot be used from another thread. If
>   you want to use an incoming connection from another thread, you need
>   to override incomingConnection().

So, you must create your own `Server` class, that inherits from the QTcpServer, and override `incomingConnection()` there. In that overriden method you have to post the socket descriptor to other thread where your TCP client will live processing that connection. In this simple example we just emit a signal.

```
signals:

   void myNewConnectionSignal(DescriptorType);

protected:

  void incomingConnection(DescriptorType descriptor)
  {
      emit myNewConnectionSignal(descriptor);
  }
```

Second, what is `NetworkSupport` thread for? I guess, you want your server object to live and work there? If so then you must rewrite it in other way. Below is the server part only. Note, that QThread already has a QEventLoop and you can use it via exec() in your run().

```
...
protected:
    MyServer *server;
...

NetworkSupport::NetworkSupport()
{
    // this is called in the main thread, so "this" lives in main thread
    server=0;
    client=0;
    // say thread to start, but it will be actually started within run()
    start();
    // sometimes it is recommended to wait here for the thread started
}

NetworkSupport::~NetworkSupport()
{
    // this is called in the main thread, say this thread to stop running
    quit();
    // wait for completion
    wait();
}

void NetworkSupport::run()
{
    // this is called in server thread
    server=new MyServer();
    if (server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5200))
    {
      // connect our new signal to slot where we create and init the TCP client, note that Qt::QueuedConnection is used because we want acceptConnection to run in the main thread
      connect(server, SIGNAL(myNewConnectionSignal(DescriptorType)), MyClientsPool, SLOT(acceptConnection(DescriptorType)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
      // go for infinite event loop
      exec();
    }
    else
    {
       // do you always ignore errors?
    }
    // the thread is stopped, let's destroy the server in the thread where it was born
    delete server;
    server=0;
}
```

Client is living and working in your main thread. You must not call its methods directly from other threads. `NetworkSupport` lives in the main thread as well: yes, it incapsulates and manages some other thread but as an QObject itself it lives in the thread we created it in. The methods below are always executed in the main thread because we connected server's signal to  NetworkSupport::acceptConnection() using Qt::QueuedConnection which says to Qt that we want the slot to be invoked in the thread where its QObject lives.

```
   private slots:

      void socketDisconnected();

...

void NetworkSupport::socketDisconnected()
{
    if (client)
    {
       client->deleteLater();
       client=0;
    }
}

void NetworkSupport::acceptConnection(DescriptorType descriptor)
{
    QTcpSocket* client=new QTcpSocket(this);
    client->setSocketDescriptor(descriptor);
    connect(client,SIGNAL(disconnected(),this,SLOT(socketDisconnected());
    connect(client,SIGNAL(readyRead(),this,SLOT(receive());
}

void NetworkSupport::receive()
{
    if (client)
      curMessage = client->readAll();
}

void NetworkSupport::sendData(QByteArray* msg)
{
    if (client)
    {
        client->write(*msg);
        client->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If we just want to hide all network works inside the thread. Note, in the example below there is little error handling and a lot of messages data copies. You might want to optimize it for production.

```
// private container class incapsulated and working in the thread
class NetworkThreadContainer : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

     public:

        NetworkThreadContainer(QObject* parent=0):QObject(parent),client(0)
        {
           if (server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5200))
            {
              connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, acceptConnection());
            }
            else
            {
                // don't you want to throw exception here?
            }        
        }

     public slots:

         void sendDataToClient(const QByteArray& barr)
         {
               if (client)
               {
                   client->write(msg);
                   client->waitForBytesWritten();
               }
         }

        void acceptConnection()
        {
            if (!client)
            {
              client = server.nextPendingConnection();
              connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receive()));            
            }
            else
            {
              // what will you do with more than one client connections or reconnections?
            }        
        }

       void NetworkSupport::receive()
       {
           if (client)
           {
              QByteArray curMessage = client->readAll();
              emit messageReceived(curMessage);
           }
       }

      signals:

         void messageReceived(const QByteArray&);

      public:

        QTcpClient* client;
        QTcpServer server;
};

// thread class visible to outer program
class NetworkThread : public QThread
{
     Q_OBJECT

     public:

        NetworkThread(QObject* parent=0):QObject(parent)
        {
           start();
        }

        ~NetworkThread()
        {
           quit();
           wait();
        }

         bool sendDataToClient(QByteArray* barr)
         {
              bool ok=false;
              // async send data to container's thread
              mutex.lock();
              if (container)
              {
                ok=true;
                QMetaObject::invokeMethod(
                    container,
                    "sendDataToClient",
                    Qt::QueuedConnection,
                    Q_ARG(QByteArray, *barr)
                );                             
              }
              else
              {
                 // container either is not ready yet or already destroyed 
              }
              mutex.unlock();
              return ok;
         }    

     signals:

        void messageReceived(const QByteArray&);

     protected:

        void run()
        {
            mutex.lock();
            // I would suggest to catch exception here and assign the error result to some variable for further processing
            container=new NetworkThreadContainer();
            mutex.unlock();
            connect(container,SIGNAL(messageReceived(QByteArray),this,SIGNAL(messageReceived(QByteArray)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
            exec();
            mutex.lock();    
            delete container;
            mutex.unlock();
        }   

     private:

        QMutex mutex;
        QPointer<NetworkThreadContainer> container;   
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that precise answer, I have to agree at some points but please give me some time to have a closer look

Comment: @user3085931 Actually it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve using multithreading here. Do you want all network processing including sending/receiving client data to be performed in separate thread? In my answer I rewritten a little bit your code and made explanations how it works but it does not solve this task exactly.

Comment: actually I don't worry to much how exactly it is implemented. I started without the threading for the network class first, but durring execution there were always these QThread-errors (like mentioned above). I assume this behaviour comes by how this program is used. It (the main application) is actually used as a plugin of a bigger program (where I unfortunately have no insight to) and to apply multiple plugins, I guess the designer(s) use threads per each plugin. This now (as it looks like) interferes with Signal/Slots registration as shown above. So I need to tell them it's all one thread.

Comment: In case you want to hide everything inside the thread it would be easier than I wrote. I'll make an update how it could be implemented.

Comment: I'm not around the project right now but I'm inspecting it closer when I return. Thanks once already.

Comment: I've implemented your *update-code* and I guess I found a few mistakes (`public QTcpClient* client` -> `public QTcpSocket* client` and `NetworkThread(QObject* parent=0):QObject(parent)` -> `NetworkThread(QThread* parent=0):QThread(parent)`), he only received Signals when I added `container->moveToThread(this->thread());` in `NetworkThread::run();` However the original error message stays the same

Comment: @user3085931 When you `container->moveToThread(this->thread());` you put the container back to tha main thread, `this` here is already a thread object and this is the thread where you want the container to stay in, while `this->thread()` is the main thread where you created your `NetworkThread` and where the `NetworkThread` lives itself. It is useful to put `qDebug()<<"Method ID, current thread "<<QThread::currentThread() << " object thread "<<obj->thread();` in each method including constructor and destructor and you'll see the threads.

Comment: The signal/slot connection didn't work because there is probably no `QEventLoop` running in your main thread where you instantiate the `NetworkObject`.